# QuickFix4J is truncating repeated groups in the FIX messsage

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixj, data-dictionary

I have a FIX message as a string, and I am creating a message object from this message using QuickFix4J, so that I can send it to the other party.

The DataDictionary that I am using is given to me by the other party.

But when I resolve it with the DD and create the message, many fields especially the ones that are repeating are getting truncated. Basically when a group of field repeats, the final message has only ONE instance of the repeating fields.

This is my original message:

```
8=FIXT.1.1|9=1288|35=X|34=1163|49=XX|52=20190410-10:27:43|56=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|131=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX_2019410_155743|146=1|55=[X/X]|48=58013XXX5|22=1|6360=XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX|454=1|455=XX58013XXX54|456=4|20200=2|20201=1|20202=6|20203=99.06300000|20204=1111.00|20205=3|20206=XXX2|20201=2|20202=6|20203=0.14400000|20204=2222.00|20205=3|20206=XXX2|460=3|1227=XXXX|29703=XXXX XXXX|167=XXXX|541=20350410|225=20170410|223=0.03500000|106=XXXXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXX XXXX XXX XXXX XXXXX|107=XXX  3.500  3/1/27 X26|873=20170309|54=2|38=188000|64=20190412|15=XXX|126=20190410-10:32:43|60=20190410-10:27:43|663=1|699=9128286X1|761=1|29715=XX9128286X18|29716=4|29717=XXX|29718=0.02625000|29719=20290215|423=6|453=7|448=XXXXXXX1|447=X|452=11|802=1|523=XXXXXXX XXXXXX XX XXX|803=9|448=XXXX|447=X|452=13|448=XXX XXXXXXXXXX 5|447=X|452=13|448=XXXXXX33|447=X|452=17|802=1|523=0355|803=17|448=XXXX|447=X|452=17|448=XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX (XXX) XXX|447=X|452=17|448=XXXXXXX|447=X|452=13|58=XXXXXX5 (XXXXXXXXXX, XXXXXXX XXXXXX XX XXX)  XXXXXXXX  XXX XX $100,000 XXX 3.500 03/01/27 X26, XXXXXXXXX XXX 2.625 02/29, XXX XX 2 XXXX XXXXX-XXXXXXX , XXXX XXXX.|5625=2|20117=10155743|5961=XXXXXX|5626=3|20012=1 3|5215=X|5627=XXXXXXXXX|5630=XXXXXXX, XXXX|20120=X2X-XXX-XXXX|21031=X|21032=X|20013=0.3|29724=60|22203=XXXX|29741=000X|29742=1000|10=144|
```

And this is the message after creating the message object:

```
8=FIXT.1.1|9=262|35=X|34=656|49=XX|52=20190410-10:27:45.566|56=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|131=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX_2019410_155743|146=1|55=[X/X]|48=58013XXX5|22=1|6360=XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX|454=1|455=XX58013XXX54|456=4|20200=2|20201=2|20202=6|20203=99.06300000|20204=1111.00|20205=3|20206=XXX2|10=111|
```

This is the code with which I am creating the message:

```
rawMessage = new Message(newmessage, dataDictionary, false);

Session.sendToTarget(rawMessage, sessionID)
```

Is there a way I can send the message as is without quickfix4j trying to resolve it and hence truncating fields. Unfortunately I can't share the DD.

Comment: Did you censor out `8=FIXT.1.1`?  Why?  That's not proprietary.  That's very important for readers to know.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier Sorry, I masked it generically. Have restored that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Grant for your inputs, finally we  figured out that the error was that repeating groups were coming out of order:

`datadictionary.setCheckUnorderedGroupFields(false);`

solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues:

**First issue: Your approach is a mistake**

```
rawMessage = new Message(newmessage, dataDictionary, false);
Session.sendToTarget(rawMessage, sessionID)
```

You can't do that!  The sequence numbers, timestamps, etc are not valid anymore!

Are you creating a naive message replayer?  (Why do people keep trying to do that?)  It's not going to work!  FIX messages flows have state that you can't just blindly replay.

If you're creating a test harness, it needs to be smarter than this.  Stop what you're doing and reconsider your approach.

**Second issue: your DD probably has errors**

Truncated repeating groups always means a DataDictionary problem.  The DD is not matching the message being parsed.  One of the following is surely happening:

- the message has put a field in the group that is not in the DD's definition for that group
- the message's group has fields out of order (compared to the DD's order)

When parsing a group, the engine will end the group as soon as it sees a field that it does not expect.

> The DataDictionary that I am using is given to me by the other party.

Don't trust it!  Counterparties make errors with their own docs, because they don't actually use them, or because their internal version are newer than what they've published.

Start parsing your message manually against the DD that they gave you, and I bet you'll find the error.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. My code is an acceptor. My code picks up FIX messages from a file written by QA Automation Scripts and I send it to an initiator. For our particular scenario this works. I have n't had issues with timestamp etc. And it works for most messaages. Only issue is with this particular message and data dictionary combo. So wanted to check if it is really DD issue, or anything I can do in my code. And unfortunately I as a developer cannot access the DD. Will ask them to check if they have any more updated DD.

Comment: Your Acceptor does have a DD.  Your Acceptor's config file will be pointing to it.  That's what it's using to parse the incoming message.

Comment: Thanks Grant. The DD seems to be latest but it does have custom fields. Do I have to re-build quickfix4j with this new DD?

Comment: If it is receiving custom repeating groups, you can get away with not rebuilding.  If it is _sending_ custom repeating groups, you probably ought to regenerate and rebuild.